# Spring Data Mongodb with QueryDsl

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, querydsl

```
 plugins {
     id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.6'
     id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version '1.0.10' }
 
 
 configurations {
     compileOnly {
         extendsFrom annotationProcessor
     } }
 
 repositories {
     mavenCentral() }
 
 ext {
     queryDslVersion = "5.0.0" }
 
 
 dependencies {
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
   
     //for querydsl
     implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:${queryDslVersion}"
     annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}" }
 
 tasks.named('test') {
     useJUnitPlatform() }
 
 def querydslDir = "$buildDir/generated/querydsl"
 
 querydsl {
     springDataMongo = true
     querydslSourcesDir = querydslDir }
 
 sourceSets {
     main.java.srcDir querydslDir }
 
 configurations {
     querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath }
 
 compileQuerydsl {
     options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl }
```

error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.createCluster(MongoClientImpl.java:219)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'com.mongodb.ServerApi com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.getServerApi()'
```

The calling method's class, com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/4.4.2/~/mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.2.jar!/com/mongodb/client/internal/MongoClientImpl.class
jar:file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.8/~/mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar!/com/mongodb/client/internal/MongoClientImpl.class
```

The calling method's class was loaded from the following location:

```
file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/4.4.2/~/mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.2.jar
```

The called method's class, com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.8/~/mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar!/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings.class
jar:file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.4.2/~/mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar!/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings: file:~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.8/~/mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl and com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings

1. Help me Plese  Can't I use spring-data-starter-mongodb with
   QueryDsl?

Answer (score 2):

`com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:5.0.0` provides a dependency `org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12` which is outdated.

Instead of `mongo-java-driver` you should use `mongodb-driver-core` (provided automatically by `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`). You can find more details here: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3134

So, you can simply replace

```
implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:${queryDslVersion}"
```

with:

```
implementation('com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb') {
    exclude group: 'org.mongodb', module: 'mongo-java-driver'
}
```

This will prevent `querydsl-mongodb` from using the old driver.